# Increment-decrement in c

Tags: increment, decrement

If

```
void main()
{ 
  int i=2,j=4; 
  i=+++i+j; //is not an error 
  i=---i+j; // is a L-value required error..
}
```

could anyone please explain in detail the concept behind multiple increments and decrements..

Comment: ...Please explain the concept of writing unreadable code

Comment: What are you intending to do with these multiple increments and decrements?

Comment: sorry about writing unreadable code...but could you explain me in the context of this question..

Comment: Actually it was input/output questions in one of my exam..

Comment: @user2132128 - If you writing unreadable code then it is difficult to maintain/understand. If you write code that is readable then you do not run into this problem in the first place. So to answer your question - do not write unreadable code

Comment: Actually i don't use stackoverflow regularly..sorry for that..

Comment: @user2132128 - It is nowt to do with SO. Just write readable code

Comment: i have already apologized twice on the same..could you please leave that..

Comment: I don't see any multiple increments or decrements, you're just mixing the +/- operator with the ++/-- operator, and '+1' is getting treated different that '-1'.

Answer (score 0):

I think the parser is not able to parse it in the format it wants it to be. Try using parenthesis as below. It would work.

i=-(--i)+j;

Comment: The question is what's different about the `-` operator and the `+` operator that the first one works.

Comment: exactly sir..could you please explain me why first one works..

Comment: In both cases the program exhibits undefined behaviour and the output could be anything.
1. main should return int not void. In C returning void is an extension that not all compilers support making the code non-portable, in C++ it is just undefined behaviour.
2. both cases break the part of the standard that specifies variable may not be accessed more than once between sequence points where at least one of those accesses is to alter the variables value. The standard states that in such a case the behaviour will be undefined.
I suggest you look sequence points and undefined behaviour on web.